# Clarification on URLs issued by Bokeh Server

Tags: bokeh

I'm in the early stages of getting my Flask application together with its routing and what not and am gearing up to lay out the `<iframe>` tags I intend to populate with pages issued from Bokeh Server.

My Webapp will hold many identical views just served from different data slices of a DataFrame. I just want to get a sense of how Bokeh structures its URLs and what the governing parameters are for the structure it adopts and how I can control them. Some of the examples I've seen seem to suggest that I create a Bokeh document per port number or something, but I'm likely missing some point. Is there anything analogous to Flask parameterized routes that I could organize on the Bokeh end?

In a nutshell what are the possibilities for the form/structure of URLs Bokeh can support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default URL structure is

```
http://host.com/appname:port
```

you can control the port (for all apps on a given server) with the `--port` command line option. Additionally, you and add a prefix (again, for all apps on a given server) with the `--prefix` option.

For example `--port=8080 --prefix=foo/bar` results in

```
http://host.com/foo/bar/appname:8080
```

That's about it. For more sophisticated needs you'll want to run a bokeh server behind some sort of proxy that maps URLs in the way you need. Some examples are the [Basic Reverse Proxy Setup](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#basic-reverse-proxy-setup) section of the user's guide.